# Setting up factory girl in Rails 5. Docs seem to leave out an important step

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot, ruby-on-rails-5

What am I doing wrong? It seems like nowhere in the docs does it say to put:

```
require 'factory_girl_rails'
require 'support/factory_girl'
```

in your rails_helper.

This is my setup without the two lines:

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '>= 5.0.0.beta3', '< 5.1'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'puma'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5.x'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'carrierwave_direct'
gem "mini_magick"

group :development, :test do
  gem 'pry'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.0'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'database_cleaner', '~> 1.5', '>= 1.5.1'
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '~> 3.0'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

User model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :images
end
```

Factories.rb file inside spec:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    sequence(:name) { |n| "jeff#{n}" }
    after(:build) do |user, eval|
      user.images << build(:image)
    end
  end


  factory :image do
    avatar File.open(File.join(Rails.root, '/spec/support/images/blueapron.jpg'))
  end
end
```

This is my spec/models/user_spec.rb:

```
describe User do

  before(:each) do
    @user = create(:user)
  end
  describe "images" do
    it "should have multiple images" do
        require 'pry' ; binding.pry

        @user.images.create({document_file:File.open(File.join(Rails.root, '/spec/fixtures/files/image.png'))})
        @user.images.create({document_file:File.open(File.join(Rails.root, '/spec/fixtures/files/image.png'))})

        @user.images.length.should eq(3)
    end
  end
end
```

When I run my tests:

```
Failures:

  1) User images should have multiple images
     Failure/Error: @user = create(:user)
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `create' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::User::Images:0x007fea80756f08>
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:4:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

AFter I include those two lines back into my rails_helper:

```
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require 'spec_helper'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'factory_girl_rails'
require 'support/factory_girl'
```

All of a sudden it works now:

```
 before(:each) do
     4:     @user = create(:user)
     5:   end
     6:   describe "images" do
     7:     it "should have multiple images" do
 =>  8:         require 'pry' ; binding.pry
     9:
    10:         @user.images.create({document_file:File.open(File.join(Rails.root, '/spec/fixtures/files/image.png'))})
    11:         @user.images.create({document_file:File.open(File.join(Rails.root, '/spec/fixtures/files/image.png'))})
    12:
    13:         @user.images.length.should eq(3)

[1] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::User::Images>)> @user
=> #<User:0x007f86e86cbcd8 id: 1, name: "jeff2", created_at: Thu, 17 Mar 2016 04:39:42 UTC +00:00, updated_at: Thu, 17 Mar 2016 04:39:42 UTC +00:00>
```

I don't even remember where I found those two lines. Is it in the docs anywhere to include those lines?

Comment: I realize you said Rails 5, but explicitly including isn't required in Rails 4 (it's enough to have factory_girl_rails in your Gemfile), so perhaps factory_girl_rails just isn't tuned up for Rails 5 yet.

Comment: In ```spec/In rails_helper.rb``` have you commented the config for other fixture path i.e. ```config.fixture_path = "...."``` which comes by default to enable factory_girl to replace the fixture instead.

Answer (score 0):

In your factory, you use **build**:

```
after(:build) do |user, eval|
  user.images << build(:image)
end
```

And in your specs you use **create**:

```
describe User do
  before(:each) do
    @user = create(:user)
  end
```

You have to use same hook, I recommend you to:

- Use **build** instead of create and save record in your before(:each) block
- Include another hook for **after(:create)** in your factory and create (not build) an image